# Create spaces between lines in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, textview

How can I create space between lines on TextView Android Development?
for Example:
I have a RecyclerView and my RecyclerView item has a Textview with 3Line Text and I want to create space between text Lines.

Comment: please add this attribute in recycler item textview `android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"`  to add space between two lines

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

and for your question, you can make a custom decorator like so

```
class MarginItemDecoration(private val spaceHeight: Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, 
    parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
    with(outRect) {
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
            top = spaceHeight
        }
        left =  spaceHeight
        right = spaceHeight
        bottom = spaceHeight
    }
  }
}
```

and add it to your Recycler view

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(MarginItemDecoration(
    resources.getDimension(R.dimen.default_padding).toInt()))
```

taken from here [Right way of setting margin on Recycler View’s cell](https://medium.com/@elye.project/right-way-of-setting-margin-on-recycler-views-cell-319da259b641)

Answer (score 0):

Try function

setLineSpacing(float add, float mult)

which sets line spacing. Each line other than the last line will have its height multiplied by mult and have add added to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a margin attribute for your text views

```
 android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:lineSpacingExtra` attribute in TextView recyclerview's item. Like below:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dummy_text"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"/>
```

Change value of `android:lineSpacingExtra` according to your need.

Without LinespacingExtra the output is like:

[image]

With LinespacingExtra the output is like:

[image]

I hope its work for you.

Answer (score -1):

If you use android studio and you want to add from xml.
Use space on layout.

If you want to change it from string,
use control character, like \n

Example:

```
I eat some apple,\n\n\n and i want to drink some water.
```

It will out like this:

```
I eat some apple,


and i want to drink some water.
```